# Get the total time every time a truck has no speed in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in SQL Server 2014:

```
Vehicle_Id |  Speed  |     Event    |     Datetime
-----------+---------+--------------+----------------------
1          |    0    |  Door-Open   |   2019-05-04 15:00:00
1          |    0    |  Door-Closed |   2019-05-04 15:15:00
1          |    50   |  Driving     |   2019-05-04 15:35:00
1          |    0    |  Parked      |   2019-05-04 15:50:00
1          |    0    |  Door-Open   |   2019-05-04 15:51:00
1          |    0    |  Door-Closed |   2019-05-04 15:52:00
1          |    50   |  Driving     |   2019-05-04 15:57:00
```

I need to identify blocks within a `datetime` in which the truck has been on `speed = 0` for more than an hour. So every time a row appears with speed 0, it should create a unique `block_id` until a row with `speed` appears. So the total time should be the first time the truck has speed 0 until the next row it finds with `speed > 0`.

Expected Output:

```
Vehicle_Id |  Speed  |     Event    |     Datetime           |     Block   | Total_State_Time_Block(Minutes)
-----------+---------+--------------+------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------
1          |    0    |  Door-Open   |   2019-05-04 15:00:00  |       1     |      35 Minutes
1          |    0    |  Door-Closed |   2019-05-04 15:15:00  |       1     |      35 Minutes
1          |    50   |  Driving     |   2019-05-04 15:35:00  |       2     |      15 Minutes
1          |    0    |  Parked      |   2019-05-04 15:50:00  |       3     |      7 Minutes
1          |    0    |  Door-Open   |   2019-05-04 15:51:00  |       3     |      7 Minutes
1          |    0    |  Door-Closed |   2019-05-04 15:52:00  |       3     |      7 Minutes
1          |    50   |  Driving     |   2019-05-04 15:57:00  |       4     |        ...
```

So, as it's ordered by `datetime`, the idea is to create groups of adjacent rows with `speed = 0` so I can identify the times a truck hasn't moved for more than an hour.

I tried windowing functions to get the result by vehicle and day. But I can't achieve this last step.

Comment: Show us your window function attempt

Comment: The description of your problem and your desired results are not the same.  Where is the "more than an hour" part?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `lag()`

```
select
  vehicle_id,
    speed,
    event,
    datetime,
    sum(case when speed = rnk then 0 else 1 end) over (order by datetime) as block
from
(
    select
      *,
      lag(speed) over (order by datetime) as rnk
  from myTable
) val
```

output:

```
| vehicle_id | speed | event       | datetime                 | block |
| ---------- | ----- | ----------- | ------------------------ | ----- |
| 1          | 0     | Door-Open   | 2019-05-04 15:00:00      | 1     |
| 1          | 0     | Door-Closed | 2019-05-04 15:15:00      | 1     |
| 1          | 50    | Driving     | 2019-05-04 15:35:00      | 2     |
| 1          | 0     | Parked      | 2019-05-04 15:50:00      | 3     |
| 1          | 0     | Door-Open   | 2019-05-04 15:51:00      | 3     |
| 1          | 0     | Door-Closed | 2019-05-04 15:52:00      | 3     |
| 1          | 50    | Driving     | 2019-05-04 15:57:00      | 4     |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want periods where the truck has been at `speed = 0` for an hour or more, you don't need your expected output.  Instead, you can look at the *next* value with a speed and calculate the decimal hours.

That is, you can get the blocks directly.  This gets the start of the block with the duration:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(second, datetime, coalesce(datetime, max_datetime)
               ) / (60.0 * 60) as decimal_hours
from (select t.*,
             lag(speed) over (partition by vehicle_id order by datetime) as prev_speed
             min(case when speed > 0 then datetime end) over (partition by vehicle_id order by datetime) as next_speed,
             max(datetime) over (partition by vehicle_id) as max_datetime
      from t
     ) t
where (prev_speed is null or prev_speed > 0) and
      speed = 0
```